# Hibernate Spatial 4 error unknown SQL type to be used in insert with org.postgis.PGgeometry

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, postgis

I've a issue when i try to store an hibernate spatial point to o PostgreSQL db with PostGis extensions installed.

Essentially, when I try to insert the record into the table the org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException is raised explaining that the org.postgis.PGgeometry could not be mapped into a SQL type.

The operating system is Windows 10 64 bit.
The PostgreSQL server Database version is 9.6 64 bit on localhost
The PostGis version is 2.3.2 64 bit
The Tomcat version is 8.5.8
The JVM version is 1.8.0_112-b15
The Spring version is 4.1.4.RELEASE
The Aspectj version is 1.8.4
The Hibernate version is 4.3.5.Final
The PostGis JDBC driver version is 1.5.2
The hibernate dialect has been set to org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
The datasource on Tomcat has been configured in this way:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/safetyAroundSchool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="2" maxIdle="2" maxWait="10000" username="biotope-xxxx" password="xxxxxxxxxx" driverClassName="org.postgis.DriverWrapper" url="jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://localhost:5432/biotope-ssp"/>
```

But I've also used:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/safetyAroundSchool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="2" maxIdle="2" maxWait="10000" username="biotope-xxxx" password="xxxxxxxxxxx" DriverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/biotope-ssp"/>
```

This is the the field declaration:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "Geometry", nullable = true)
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Point location;
```

The table is created with the correct geometry type for the column this is the create script:

```
CREATE TABLE public.issue
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    date timestamp without time zone,
    location geometry,
    longdesc character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    shortdesc character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    type bigint,
    userid bigint,
    CONSTRAINT issue_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And this is the error that i receive when I try to insert a new record.

> 18:14:11,878  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07006
>   18:14:11,883 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Non è possibile identificare il tipo SQL da usare per l'istanza di tipo «org.postgis.PGgeometry». Usare «setObject()» specificando esplicitamente il tipo da usare per questo valore.
>   18:14:11,898 ERROR WebApiExceptionProcessor:28 - Internal server error intercepted
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not insert: [it.holonix.safetyAroundSchoold.entity.Issue]; SQL [insert into Issue (date, location, longDesc, shortDesc, type, userId, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [it.holonix.safetyAroundSchoold.entity.Issue]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:515)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
>       at it.holonix.safetyAroundSchoold.controller.IssueCtrl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6840c31.insertIssue()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at it.holonix.webapi.auth.AuthRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(AuthRequestWrapperFilter.java:23)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at it.holonix.webapi.util.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [it.holonix.safetyAroundSchoold.entity.Issue]
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3144)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
>       ... 54 more
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Non è possibile identificare il tipo SQL da usare per l'istanza di tipo «org.postgis.PGgeometry». Usare «setObject()» specificando esplicitamente il tipo da usare per questo valore.
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:967)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:188)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:188)
>       at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.AbstractJTSGeometryValueBinder.bind(AbstractJTSGeometryValueBinder.java:48)
>       at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.AbstractJTSGeometryValueBinder.bind(AbstractJTSGeometryValueBinder.java:39)
>       at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
>       at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
>       at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
>       ... 66 more

The quote in italian could be translated in this way:
It's not possible to identify the SQL type to be used for the instance of type «org.postgis.PGgeometry». Use «setObject()» specifying the type to be used for this value.

Could you help me to solve this issue? Do you need some other information?

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check that you actually use the Hibernate Postgis dialect. Normally you should find log messages during start up to that effect. If you let Spring choose the dialect for you, it will not pick the Hibernate Postgis dialect.

Secondly, you don't need any Postgis JDBC driver or driver wrapper. Hibernate Spatial works with the standard JDBC drivers. You may want to follow [this tutorial](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/02-Tutorial/01-tutorial4/) to get a feel for how everything should be set up.

Comment: The dialect selected is correct, also the drivers, they work fine with all the others data type.

Comment: Yes, the drivers will work fine for all _other_ datatypes. But Hibernate Spatial is designed to work with the standard Postgresql JDBC driver, and not a driver that tries to modify the _Geometry_ types.

Comment: I've solved the problem, into the pom.xml I've specified scope provided for postgis-jdbc